# Jacobian matrix of an inverse diffeomorphism

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ be a function defined as $f(x,y,z)=(x-xy, xy-xyz, xyz)$ and $\Omega=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:xy\neq0\}$ an open set.

As f is an injective function in $\Omega$ and $detJ_f(x,y,z)=x^2y\neq0\forall(x,y,z)\in\Omega$, we know that $f$ is a diffeomorphism from $\Omega$ to $f(\Omega)$.

We also know that the Jacobian matrix of the inverse diffeomorphism is defined in all $(x,y,z)\in\Omega$ as the inverse of $J_f$, the Jacobian matrix of $f$.

But my question is: can I calculate the Jacobian matrix of $f^{-1}$ in a point like $(0,0,1)$, that doesn't belong to $\Omega$? I know that $J_{f^{-1}}(0,0,1)$ is not defined as the $J_f^{-1}(0,0,1)$, but is it defined in any other way? Is there a way to calculate $J_{f^{-1}}(0,0,1)$?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular example, you managed to produce a multivariate function, where it is relatively easy to find the inverse (at points where it is defined, of course), thanks to the fact that $x\mapsto x+\text{something}$: $x$ can be reobtained by sending $\phi:(x,y,z)\mapsto x+y+z$ (you may check that $\phi\circ f\equiv x$). Continuing with $y$ and $z$, we find $f^{-1}:(x,y,z)\mapsto (x+y+z,\frac{y+z}{x+y+z},\frac{z}{y+z})$.

Does this help to obtain answers to your questions?

Comment: Is it possible that there's a typo with the $(x+y-z)$ (throughout), i.e., that they're supposed to be $(x+y+z)$?

Comment: I tried something like this, doing it "manually", but I don't know if I was supposed to do that. With the inverse calculated, I just have to obtain its Jacobian matrix and evaluate it in (0,0,1), isn't it?
Is that rigorous or do I have to prove something else to do that?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, you're right about that. It's corrected now.